# Sumatra - TeXstudio - inverse search hits not the exakt line

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I do use TeXStudio und Sumatra on Windows 10. I put in Sumatra "C:\Program Files\texstudio\texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l

If I double click on the PDF, it jumps into TeXstudio, but some lines below. What do I need to change to hit the exakt word or line?

Google and the forum shows me always the same command for sumatra, i wrote above. What could the reason be for the inaccurate work?

Comment: Any reason why you use Sumatra when TeXStudio has a build in PDF viewer that can even be popped out to be in an external window